# Steak capybara dynamic ajax element not found

Tags: ajax, dynamic, selenium, capybara

I am using capybara 0.4.1

I am having a problem for finding an element which is being dynamically loaded via ajax.

How do i use a capybara finder statement so that i can find an element loaded with ajax.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the Selenium driver for that scenario:

```
# in a new file: spec/acceptance/support/javascript.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium if example.metadata[:js]
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.use_default_driver if example.metadata[:js]
  end
end

# in your feature
scenario "Scenario that needs Javascript", :js => true do
  #...
end

scenario "Scenario that doesn't need Javascript" do
  #...
end
```

Original is here: https://gist.github.com/448487 but has been edited for deprecations.